# How do you use PhotoSwipe on Wordpress?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, photo, photoswipe

I'm trying to use Photoswipe on Wordpress (not the plugin). I've been working at it for the last 12 hours and haven't been able to get it to work. I could go into specifics, but I think at this point, I just need a ground up solution. So, to restate my question, how do you use Photoswipe on Wordpress?

If anyone has ever had any experience in doing this, or knows of a tutorial, please, let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Should be as simple as...

Putting this in your `<head>` in your theme header.php

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/js/klass.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/js/code.photoswipe-3.0.4.min.js"></script>
```

...also add this in your `<head>` below the above

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var myPhotoSwipe = $("#gallery a").photoSwipe({
            enableMouseWheel: false,
            enableKeyboard: false

            // add configuration options here

        });
    });
</script>
```

Make sure you don't forget to put these javascript files in your theme folder. As you can see I put a sub folder in your theme called 'js'

Simply build your gallery in your post in html mode, using your post images and links, wrapped in an unordered list like below.

Make sure the id of the unordered list matches the var `myPhotoSwipe = $("#gallery a").photoSwipe({` part of your script.

```
<ul id="gallery">
    <li><a href="images/full/01.jpg"><img src="images/thumb/01.jpg" alt="Image 01" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="images/full/02.jpg"><img src="images/thumb/02.jpg" alt="Image 02" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="images/full/03.jpg"><img src="images/thumb/03.jpg" alt="Image 03" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="images/full/04.jpg"><img src="images/thumb/04.jpg" alt="Image 04" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="images/full/05.jpg"><img src="images/thumb/05.jpg" alt="Image 05" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="images/full/06.jpg"><img src="images/thumb/06.jpg" alt="Image 06" /></a></li>
</ul>
```

Scripts don't have to go in your head but can before the closing `</body>` tag.

Theoretically this should do something. Then you can style or build it in else where.